# How to download old files from AOSP git

Tags: android, git, android-source

I am trying to download an old file from an old version of Android but i don't know how.

How can I download one of [these files](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/db567c390bd56c05614eaa83c02dbb99f97ad9cc/core/res/res/raw/)

Comment: did you try the .tgz link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just download the latest version click **tgz** button. You will get archive with latest files.

If you want older version, click **path history** choose point in the history, scroll to the bottom where you will see directory view. Go again to `core/res/res/raw` and then click on **tgz**. You will get archive with those files in the chosen point of history.

Answer (score 1):

As njzk2 said, there is a link to the archived version for download.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+archive/db567c390bd56c05614eaa83c02dbb99f97ad9cc/core/res/res/raw.tar.gz